# How can I stop my .htaccess file redirecting iPad users to my mobile site?

Tags: iphone, ipad, .htaccess, redirect

I my .htaccess file I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/m/$0 [R=301,L]
```

When someone logs in with an iPad he/she gets redirected =/ to the mobile version as well. I'd like them to see the normal site (without the `/m/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another one

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPad"[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```